# confused regarding forms authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Here is my config section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Now in the controller I have:

```
FormsService.SignIn(userName, true);
var temp = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

The temp value sometimes is set to false and sometimes to true. When the user is myself (valid and in the system).  Regardless of this value in my aspx page I have:

```
<% if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            { %>
```

this always resolves to true. So what am I doing wrong in my controller? And how do I check to see if the user is authenticated in the controller?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must redirect after authenticating and setting the authentication cookie. It is on the subsequent request that the user will be truly authenticated.

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    FormsService.SignIn(userName, true);
    return RedirectToAction("authenticated");
}
```

Comment: @user277498, here's the reason: when you successfully authenticate an user you add the authentication cookie to the `Response` object. On subsequent requests this cookie is sent by the client and so it is inside the `Request` object. Forms authentication module looks for the cookie in the Request object to know whether a user is authenticated or not.